# Having a problem trying to setup a simple Sconstruct 'Hello World' script

Tags: python, python-3.x, scons

Now before anyone gets on me, I have seen this question before. I know I'm not the only one with this issue, but, I tried fixing it the way people have suggested, but it did not work. please help.

I am getting the error:

`Index Error: List index out of range`

I've tried everything and nothing works. I'm sorry I'm new to this.

Here's the issue itself:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Sconstruct>s
cons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
IndexError: list index out of range:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Scon
struct\SConstruct.py", line 1:
    SConstruct: Program('HelloWorld.c')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Scri
pt\SConscript.py", line 665:
    env = self.factory()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Scri
pt\SConscript.py", line 645:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Defa
ults.py", line 88:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Envi
ronment.py", line 982:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Envi
ronment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Envi
ronment.py", line 1789:
    tool(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\__init__.py", line 296:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\default.py", line 40:
    for t in SCons.Tool.tool_list(env['PLATFORM'], env):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\__init__.py", line 1266:
    c_compiler = FindTool(c_compilers, env) or c_compilers[0]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\__init__.py", line 1169:
    if t.exists(env):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\msvc.py", line 292:
    return msvc_exists(env)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\MSCommon\vc.py", line 759:
    vcs = cached_get_installed_vcs(env)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\MSCommon\vc.py", line 524:
    ret = get_installed_vcs(env)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\MSCommon\vc.py", line 535:
    VC_DIR = find_vc_pdir(ver)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\MSCommon\vc.py", line 344:
    comps = find_vc_pdir_vswhere(msvc_version)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\scons\SCons\Tool
\MSCommon\vc.py", line 306:
    vc_pdir = os.path.join(vsdir[0], 'VC')
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I edited this thanks to Faruk13. Anyway, is this what you meant Partho63?

EDIT 2: Here's the files you requested. Sorry about that.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3e5ojuh9b5zyge/Sconstruct%20Files.zip?dl=0

EDIT 3:

I discovered the issue. Apparently Visual C didn't install right when I first installed it. Upon re-installation, it worked. Thank you everyone for your help, and sorry if I annoyed you guys with my newbish behavior. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pleas provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We can't possibly help if you don't _show us your code_.  Yes, you included the full error message, which is great, but by itself it's mostly useless.

Comment: Judging by the last line in the error, `vsdir` must be an empty list, and thus has no element `[0]`.

Comment: Please share your SConstruct file. (And if you have them SConscript files) . (That would be the minimum complete verifyier.  In other words if we copy your files to our system, we should be able to run SCons on them and see the error you get)

Comment: If I have to guess, I'd say you don't have any version of Visual C installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Visual C needs to be installed properly for Scons to build or work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This specific error message was due to a bug introduced in SCons 3.0.4. It will effect scons on windows environments in which no MSVC compiler is installed, even if you are not planning on using the MSVC compiler.

It was fixed by this pull request https://github.com/SCons/scons/pull/3288. As of writing this, SCons 3.0.4 is the latest released version, so you will need to use the master branch or go back to a previous version.